# Counter for sacred warrior 1V1

Tags: dota

Here's the scenario: Huskarr with burning spear in auto cast rushes at me with his ulti. My HP reduces to half of what it was, with his damage constantly increasing with berserker's blood (and me attacking him back and reducing his HP) and my HP reducing because of the burning spear, I die. In some cases I am left with a two digit HP, after killing him but I die anyway because others would have caught me by then.

Who is the best counter for sacred in 1v1 situations like this?

Comment: Try blademail. He will take 100% of the damage he deals to you on top of the 30% hp cast cost. That's almost suicide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To counter the specific situation you have described there are two possibilities: to escape alive, or to kill him outright. In my opinion, trying to go one-on-one with Huskar is almost always ill-advised due to his skill set. So I have broken this up with heroes that can reasonably escape while still damaging Huskar to a degree and lastly a hard counter.

### Heroes

**Windrunner** - using the `windrunner` ability, depending on level, you have from 3-5 seconds of 100% evasion, 50% increased move speed, and a small area of effect slow around your hero. While this skill can usually be advised for aggressive engagement usage, as an escape, it is ideal to run from Huskar. `Shackleshot` is also a solid escape tool depending on your ability to position yourself and predict the enemy's movement.

**Mirana** - even while being attacked, with a few steps back `arrow` and `starfall` should be relatively easy to land for either a small stun (if early levels) or a large amount of nuke damage (later levels). Huskar's skills are all based around losing health and gaining bonus damage so burst damage is your friend here. In an ideal situation you would have teammates that could follow-up with finishing the kill, but most likely you can turn at this point and `leap` toward safety. `Leap` is also a pretty solid counter to Huskar's ultimate, `Life Break`. Where `Life Break` was suppose to slow for 5 seconds, after `leap` you will gain some move speed back due to the leap move speed bonus.

**Anti-Mage** - dive in to add a few attack swipes before using blink to escape in any direction, blinking in a direction other than straight back will help as it is less expected.

**Void** - similar tactic to Anti-Mage, but using `Timewalk` instead and with the added perk of `Chronosphere` to either give you more time to attack or get away.

**[Hard Counter] Spectre** - With `desoloate` adding damage since you are one on one, and `dispersion` soaking up anywhere between 10-22% of damage dealt to you, the only large variable here is whether your items are farmed yet.

### Items

**Force staff** - push yourself in some direction *away* from attack.

**Eul's Scepter** - use on Huskar if you are alone and need to run or on yourself to allow teammates to focus down Huskar and you can rejoin a few seconds later either to use nukes that were on cd or hopefully persue a now heavily injured Huskar.

**Sheep-stick** - polymorph/hex as a counter for any carry, for the most part.

**Ghost Scepter** - you **can** still be attacked through manually casting of Huskar's orb, but this will be far far slower than if he was auto-attacking with his `berserker blood` buff.

Comment: Ahh, brilliant. Ill try this one out. Spectre seems perfect for 1v1

Comment: Just as a reminder and a common mistake, don't try to counter him with purge while he is full stack passive, it's useless.

Answer (score 2):

Necrolyte crushes him; any disabler/nuker like Lion or Lina can also melt him very easily.

Also worth noting is that having magic immunity activated causes his ultimate to deal no damage. If you pick up a BKB you should be able to react in time to his leap to negate the damage (and Burning Spears).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer counter instead of escape.

Hero's choices I have are:

- Troll -- you need lifesteal if you are under level 16.
- Ursa -- must have lifesteal (vlads only).
- Bane hallow (shadow demon literally can kill anyone in 1-1, unless the energy has bkb)
- Weaver -- need to smartly use the invi skill/ you might have to use ulti, but the chances with this are 50-50.

Items:

- Lothers - use this to simply escape, or sometimes you want to hit back since the huskers ulti has gone.
- Blade mail